# Error using Ajax in PHP and JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

i got a problem when i try to use ajax in a php file, which calls to another php file.
Here is the code of the php file:

```
<script>
        function obtenerProductos(cat) {
            parametros = {"idCat": cat};
            $.ajax({
                data: parametros,
                url: '/bin/getProductos.php',
                type: 'post',
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $(".prods > form").html("Procesando, espere por favor...");
                },
                success: function(respuesta) {
                    $(".prods > form").html(respuesta);
                }
            });
        }

        function obtenerProducto(prod) {
            parametros2 = {"idProd": prod};
            $.ajax({
                data: parametros2,
                url: '/bin/getProducto.php',
                type: 'post',
                beforeSend: function() {
                    lista = $(".cPreview").html() + "<br/> Añadiendo...";
                    $(".cPreview").html(lista);
                },
                success: function(respuesta) {
                    lista = $(".cPreview").html()+ respuesta.nombre + "\t" + respuesta.precio + "<br/>" ;
                    $(".cPreview").html(lista);
                    precio = parseFloat($(".precioT").html()) + respuesta.precio;
                    $(".precioT").html(precio);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

In the first function of this script i call to the first PHP (getProductos.php) to get all the products of a category and receive a html which print in a form.
The second function calls to another php (getProducto.php) to get all the information of the selected product and print it in another div.
Here you have the PHP files named.

**getProductos.php** (This works)

```
<?php
include '../funciones.php';
$recibido = $_POST['idCat'];
echo obtenerProductosCategorias($recibido);
?>
```

**getProducto.php** (Dont Works)

```
<?php
include '../funciones.php';
$recibido = $_POST['idProd'];
echo obtenerProductos($recibido);
?>
```

And the 2 functions of this code:

```
function obtenerProductosCategorias($idCat) {
    conectDB();
    $string = "";
    $sql = 'select * from Productos where id_categoria="' . $idCat . '";';
    $resultado = mysql_query($sql);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)) {
        $string = $string . "<input type='button' onclick='obtenerProducto(" . $row["id_producto"] . ");return false;' value='" . $row['nombre_producto'] . "' />";
    }
    return $string;
    closeDB();
}

function obtenerProductos($idProd) {
    conectDB();
    $sql = 'select * from Productos where id_producto="' . $idProd . '";';
    $resul = mysql_query($sql);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resul)) {
        $resultado["nombre"] = $row["nombre_producto"];
        $resultado["precio"] = $row["coste_producto"];
    }
   return json_encode($resultado);
   closeDB();
}
```

I have alerts inside the PHP to check that everything is going fine but the second function doesnt enter in his PHP and it returns undefined undefined without show any alert of the PHP thats why i think that the second function have some problems to reach his PHP but the URL is correct and the file is located in the right place.

Thanks for reading and sorry for my English.

Comment: Where is your JS function `obtenerProducto` called from?

Comment: echo `$query` in php and alert it in js ans check what query is executing

Comment: In the onclick event of the inputs generated by the obtenerProductosCategorias function

Answer (score 0):

Try defining $resultado as an array prior to assigning anything too it.  Not sure but in some configurations this does break PHP.

```
function obtenerProductos($idProd) {
    conectDB();
    $sql = 'select * from Productos where id_producto="' . $idProd . '";';
    $resul = mysql_query($sql);

    $resultado = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resul)) {
        $resultado["nombre"] = $row["nombre_producto"];
        $resultado["precio"] = $row["coste_producto"];
    }
   return json_encode($resultado);
   closeDB();
}
```